# Javascript Bookmarklet Unresponsive

Tags: javascript, regex, bookmarklet

Javascript newb here.  Creating a bookmarklet to automate a simple task at work.  Mostly a learning exercise.  It will scan a transcript on CNN.com, for instance: (http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1302/28/acd.01.html).  It will grab the lead stories at the top of the page, the name and title of the guests on the show, and format them so that they can be copy pasted into another document.

I've come up with a simple version that includes some jQuery that grabs the subheading and then uses a regular expression to find the names of the guests (it will also exclude everything between (begin videoclip) and (end videoclip), but I haven't gotten that far yet.  It then alerts them (will eventually print them in a pop-up window, alert is just for troubleshooting purposes).

I'm using http://benalman.com/code/test/jquery-run-code-bookmarklet/ to create the bookmarklet.  My problem is that once the bookmarklet is created it is completely unresponsive.  Click on it and nothing happens. I've tried minimizing the code first with no result.  My guess is that cnn.com's javascript is conflicting with mine but I'm not sure how to get around that.  Or do I need to include some code to load and store the text on the current page?  Here's the code (I've included comments, but I took these out when I used the bookmarklet generator.)  Thanks for any help!

```
//Grabs the subheading
var leadStories=$(".cnnTransSubHead").text();
//Scans the webpage for guest name and title.  Includes a regular expression to find any
//string that starts with a capital letter, includes a comma, and ends in a colon.  
var scanForGuests=/[A-Z ].+,[A-Z0-9 ].+:/g;
//Joins the array created by scanForGuests with a semicolon instead of a comma
var guests=scanForGuests.join(‘; ‘);
//Creates an alert in the proper format including stories and guests.
alert(“Lead Stories: “ + leadStories + “. ” + guests + “. SEE TRANSCRIPT FIELD FOR FULL TRANSCRIPT.“)
```

Comment: make sure to use `var scanForGuests` if you forget the `var` keyword it's going on the global namespace and might (though in this case is unlikely) to conflict.

Comment: Sorry that was a copy paste error.  Changed it and getting the same result.

Comment: I'm also not sure about those quotations you're using. one is `"` another is `“` - those are actually different characters.

Comment: Thank you - valuable lesson - I didn't have a text editor on the pc I was working on and assumed that all quotations were created equal.  Unfortunately still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the page. Open up developer tools (ctrl+shift+j in chrome) and paste your code in the console to see what's wrong.

---

The `$` in `var leadStories = $(".cnnTransSubHead").text();` is from jQuery and the link provided does not have jQuery loaded into the page.

On any modern browser you should be able to achieve the same results without jQuery:

```
 var leadStories = document.getElementsByClassName('cnnTransSubHead')
     .map(function(el) { return el.innerText } );
```

next we have:

```
var scanForGuests=/[A-Z ].+,[A-Z0-9 ].+:/g;
var guests=scanForGuests.join('; ');
```

scanForGuests IS a regular expression, you never actually matched it to anything - so `.join()` is going to throw an error. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. Are you trying to scan the full text of the page for that regex?  In that case something like this would be your best bet

```
document.body.innerText.match(scanForGuests);
```

keep in mind that while `innerText` removes html markup, it's far from perfect and what pops up in it is very much at the mercy of how the page's html is structured.  That said, on my quick test it seems to work.

Finally, for something like this you should use an [immediately invoked function](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) or you're sticking all your variables into the global context.

So putting it all together you get something like this:

```
(function() {
     var leadStories = document.getElementsByClassName('cnnTransSubHead')
         .map(function(el) { return el.innerText } );
    var scanForGuests=/[A-Z ].+,[A-Z0-9 ].+:/g;
    var guests = document.body.innerText.match(scanForGuests).join("; ");
    alert("Leads: " + leadStories + " Guests: " + guests);
})();
```

Comment: That works perfectly.  Immensely helpful.  Especially the console tip... I was testing in JSbin but then didn't know how to link it to the site.  Thank you!